# starting JVM from C++ application running on Wine

Tags: java, c++, ubuntu, jvm, java-native-interface

I've been developing a C++-program written for Windows that starts JVM to delegage some tasks to it. On Windows it works well: all needed paths are contained in PATH so JVM.dll and all its dependencies are available to be used.

The problem appears when I'm trying to use the very .exe-file to start it on Ubuntu via Wine. As I understand, for it to work correctly, I should put all needed libraries somewhere on filesystem assotiated with Wine, but the machine (Ubuntu) where the program is to be run will already have Java installed (I did not wanted to oblige somebody to add additional libraries in Wine-directory. So can I ask .exe-file running on Wine to create JVM using Ubuntu's Java? And what should the path to .jar that I'm going to use look like? For Windows it is something like this:
"C:\\Users\***\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JChartApp\\dist\\JChartApp.jar"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you would have to install a `Windows` version of the `JVM` in `wine` on the `Ubuntu` system. I'd be surprised if that worked particularly well. Is the `C++` program completely unportable that you can't compile it in `Ubuntu`?

Comment: There was a decision (not mine) to use the only one version built on Windows and, in case of Linux, run it using Wine.

Comment: Just to clarify this: Java is platform-independent (i.e. the bytecode can be run on any OS, as long as you have a JVM installed). But the JVM itself is NOT platform-independent. What you are trying to do is to start a  Linux-JVM from within a Windows-Program. Where should the JVM run? It cannot run on the Windows-Side since it is compiled for Linux. And it cannot run on the Linux-Side since Windows does not know anything about the host system. I do not think this is possible in any way.